# Is is possible to have "bad" electricity in your home?

Tags: electrical

I live in a small 5-unit condominium building in a city and have noticed that light bulbs are constantly popping well ahead of their anticipated shelf life and other electronic equipment (most of it baby stuff, I have a newborn) is breaking again sooner than it should.  Is is possible to have a problem with the electricity in a building / unit and, if so, what should I be checking / how do I speak to an electrician to assess and fix the situation.

Forgive my naivety on this subject...

Comment: Tester101 has the answer below, but I'll add on. Voltage spikes and dips caused by increased demand will create these problems. Factories on the same line are typically the cause for most areas, but in others it can really just be from the draw of the amount of people around. I'd suggest using some surge protectors on what you can.

Comment: As far as light bulbs go, other reasons bulbs burn out too fast include bad sockets that produce excess heat, or using the incorrect style or size of bulb for the fixture enclosing it (heat dissipation).  Low voltage however tends to lengthen the life of bulbs.  Do you see any flickering or brightness changed when the light is just on?

Comment: There's no longer any reason to buy CFL, especially around a baby, but LED is a great way to go.  Get non-dimmable types rated 100-240 volts (ie world market, Japan to UK). They can adapt to this voltage range on the fly, which makes them impervious to voltage surges in that range.  Really cheap LEDs will also fail, so avoid the bottom shelf: Lights of America, Feit Electric, Lifebulb etc.  Weirdly, Ikea stuff is surprisingly good but still cheap.  I also see GE bulbs as low as $3 but they are not multivoltage.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.  Apologies for the delays (wasn't getting notifications on this question for some reason).  I am going to purchase the Kill-a-watt and see what results from that.  I am using CFL, but will switch to LED moving forward.  I do have dimmers on a lot of my ceiling lighting though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's definitely possible to have poor power quality, which can lead to shortened life of devices.  It's possible for this to be caused by poor wiring in the building, though it's more commonly a problem with the distribution system.

In areas where utilities are older, it's common for the distribution systems to be overloaded by higher consumer demand.  This can lead to voltage fluctuations, which can be rough on electrical devices.

An electrician can monitor the system, and diagnose power quality problems. However,  they may be limited in their ability to solve the problem. The building owner may not be willing to pay for the repair, or the problem may be outside the building.

Answer (score 2):

Even for a novice, I would suggest basic, inexpensive test equipment like a $20 Kill-a-Watt, sold on Amazon or Menards (there are also more featureful alternatives for a little more money).

If you're blowing a lot of stuff, my first thought is you have high voltage.  There's a specific thing to watch for: a lost neutral.   American power is 240V with a "neutral" that splits it into 120 and 120. If that neutral has a problem, the two "sides" will still add up to 240V, but each side will be over or under 120V, often by quite a lot. This will fry things and potentially start fires.  A gadget like a Kill-a-Watt can help you spot this.

One workaround to surges generally, is to watch for electronic gadgets with switch mode power supplies, rated 100-240V (world market). They will ride through any voltage in that range, and a common surge suppressing power strip or outlet adapter will take care of anything over 240V.

For instance multi-voltage LED bulbs will solve your bulb blow problem.  Don't buy CFLs with a baby around (they're obsolete anyway) but LEDs are safe. And they have arrived in terms of color and quality at a reasonable price.

Comment: Out of curiosity can you tell me the names of the "more featureful alternatives" to the Kill-a-watt so I can do my due diligence on Amazon before I buy something?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but search Amazon for "kill a watt" and I'm sure it will have lots of alternative suggestions.